# libgdx - Image setDrawable not working

Tags: java, libgdx

Changing the Actor(Image subclass) texture at runtime doesn't work.
Only the texture argument of the constructor call is drawn. I searched for
a solution, but nothing did work. Last try was looking up the code in the
Image constructor, which ultimately just sets the Drawable und then calls
setSize().

CircuitElement extends Image

```
public class Bulb extends CircuitElement {
    boolean on;
    int x, y;

    TextureRegion bulbOn;
    TextureRegion bulbOff;

    public Bulb (int x, int y, int id, TextureRegion i) {
        super(i);

        on = false;
        //this.x = x;
        //this.y = y;
        this.id = id;

        TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("switch.pack"));
        bulbOn = atlas.findRegion("bulbOn");
        bulbOff = atlas.findRegion("bulbOff");
        setWidth(bulbOn.getRegionWidth());
        setHeight(bulbOn.getRegionHeight());
        setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        debug();

        this.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                if (on) {
                    on = false;
                } else {
                    on = true;
                }
                System.out.println(on);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void draw (Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        if (on) {
            setDrawable(new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(bulbOn)));
            //setWidth(bulbOn.getRegionWidth());
            //setHeight(bulbOn.getRegionHeight());
            //setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            setSize(getPrefWidth(), getPrefHeight());
        } else {
            setDrawable(new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(bulbOff)));
            //setWidth(bulbOff.getRegionWidth());
            //setHeight(bulbOff.getRegionHeight());
            //setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            setSize(getPrefWidth(), getPrefHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should switch the drawable in the `ClickListener`. Don't create new objects like that in `draw()` as it will result in the garbage collector going nuts in your game. Furthermore, you can simplify the toggle via `on = !on`.

Comment: @noone: Thank you for the good suggestions, I will change code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to call super.draw() in my own draw-method, after
calling setDrawable and setSize.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass any `Drawable` as the constructor argument of `Image` during initialization. Then you can change the `Drawable` at runtime using `setDrawable()`. It is some bug in the `Image` class.

```
// initialize
Image kidImage = new Image(dummyDrawable);
// instead of Image kidImage = new Image();
..
..
// run time
kidImage.setDrawable(realDrawable);
```

This will definitely work.